# Tmux 2.6 copy-mode key-binding

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

I have got a problem with key-binding in copy-mode in Tmux. It worked perfectly before the last dist-upgrade. Now Tmux is in version 2.6.

Here is a part of my `tmux.conf` file:

```
54 # Copy
55 set-window-option -g mode-keys vi
56 bind -n M-c copy-mode -e
57 bind -T vi-copy 'v' begin-selection
58 bind -T vi-copy 'y' copy-selection
```

Here is the error I get when I start Tmux:

```
/home/phantom/.tmux.conf:57: unknown command: begin-selection
/home/phantom/.tmux.conf:58: unknown command: copy-selection
```

Comment: See the man page, the syntax has changed; eg., `bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'v' send-keys -X begin-selection`

Comment: @jasonwryan I think the man page is not really intuitive for this. But it works. Thanks, you can add it as an answer if you want.